# How to connect use cases with each other?

Tags: uml, diagram, visio, use-case, argouml

I'm setting the use cases of a project, here are some of the details :

My question is two parts :

**first one :**

I have an actor user.
The user can register on the website.
He can login, view profile, edit password.

> Regarding the previous use cases, I'm confused how to visualize the use cases in the diagram, I was thinking it might be done like the following :

[image]

1. Create a use case "Manage Profile" and connect the other use cases "View Profile,Edit password, etc..." to it with a generalize relationship. and then connect that use case to the "loginCheck" use case with a "include relationship". The actor will indicate "manage profile".
2. Create a sub-system "Profile" and set the use cases related to within it. then connect it to "loginCheck" with "include relationship". The actor will indicate each use case.

**second one :**

The user can Add bet : there are some types of bets:

- mutual bet : 
  1- single bets. 
  2- combination bets
- long term bets
- championship bets

> Should I create a general use case "AddBet" and extend the other types to it.
>   [image]

I can't upload photo directly because I'm new .

Comment: Empty arrows you used on the diagram, mean: thing A is a case of thing B. For example, admin and user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, For me I saw a lot of "link" inside your diagram which seems to be use in a wrong way. Maybe you can take a look at some UML ressources and more specifically, association, generalization, include and extend links... BTW I am just curious to know which tool do you use for this? Visio or ArgoUML?

So now concerning your(s) question(s).

1. When you want to associate an actor to an usecase you have to create an association between them not a generalization
2. If you want to specifiy that an "manage profile" use case  can include (or not) changing password, view its profile, etc for this I would use an extend link.
3. For modelling the fact that an given use case mandatory include another one I would use include relationship.
4. the creation of an "add bet" use case "exntended" by the other one would indicate that you have a lot in commmon between all this possible bet.

Please take a look at my screenshots and let discuss about it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've added an answer, would you please find it.

Comment: MR. Red Beard : thanks for your reply. I'm using visio 2013 . but the uploaded photos were made by visio 2007 because of some technical issues "so, I meant 'association' not 'generalization' between actor & usecases".

Now I changed them, and they become like :

membership : http://i.stack.imgur.com/EJCkR.jpg

betting : http://i.stack.imgur.com/VPykD.jpg

regarding betting : I'm confused if should I split theme because maybe each one of theme has a significantly different behaviour, but in the point of view of the user they are all "add bet".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On the Use case diag you should have only actors, visually different systems (such as terminal, client computer, server computer or Profile management system, Betting system ) and real-life actions(use cases).

Systems are shown as blocks, actors as people and use cases as ovals that connect sides of the action.

You should Profile Management as a system, as a protagonist in dialogue user-system. And you'll see, that Mobile bank is NOT a use case, is not an action. Maybe, it is another subsystem, or maybe simply won't belong there.

On your other diagram obviously different sorts of bets are descendents of the "bet" use case. They do not simply extend it.

You have many use cases not connecter to anybody. WHO does these actions? It is the target of UC diagram to show it.